# C# 7.2 proxy "by-value returns"

Tags: c#, c#-7.2

I am trying to compose and proxy ImmutableList which has

```
public ref readonly T ItemRef(int index);
```

I try:

```
public class MyImmutableList<T> {
    public readonly ImmutableList<T> Value;
    ...
    public ref readonly T ItemRef(int index) => Value.ItemRef(index);
}
```

I get:

> By-value returns may only be used in methods that return by value

What is wrong here ? and how can this be fixed ?

Comment: `public ref readonly T ItemRef(int index) => ref Value.ItemRef(index);`?

Comment: great, compiles ! can you post an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `ref` before the implicit `return`:

```
public ref readonly T ItemRef(int index) => ref Value.ItemRef(index);
```